# dashboard Error under Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, dashboard, performancepoint, dashboard-designer

I create 4 score card report in dashboard designer in SP2013,
I have SP on server and SQL on other server.
The report can access the Analysis cube and show Data.
I deploy the dashboard, once i open in it in the browser the reports gives me 
unexpected error occurs.
I have checked the event viewer for logs and SP logs and use the fiddlers nothing give an error concern this.
I am hoping for someone can assist me concern this

thanks and regards

Comment: Are you connecting using per-user identity or a shared account?

Comment: Dear Ola, 
I am Using the un-attended account